# Can open and read from file but not then resave to same file

Tags: vb.net

I am using vb.NET and windows forms.
I have a simple form with a list box and two buttons.
btnLoadData opens up an OpenFileDialog and allows me to choose the text file to open, this is then read into the list box.

I can then delete items from the list box.

btnSaveList opens up a SaveFileDialog and allows me to choose a file to save to.

The problem occurs when I try to save to the same file that I read in.
It tells me that the file cannot be accessed as it is in use.  It works if I choose a new file name.

I have searched and tried a number of different suggestions.  I have altered the code a number of times and have finally decided I need to ask for help!

The code for the two buttons is below.

```
Private Sub btnLoadData_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnLoadData.Click
        Dim openFD As New OpenFileDialog()

        openFD.Filter = "Text [*.txt*]|*.txt|CSV [*.csv]|*.csv|All Files [*.*]|*.*"

        openFD.ShowDialog()
        openFD.OpenFile()

        Dim objReader As New StreamReader(openFD.SafeFileName)
        While objReader.Peek <> -1
            lstList.Items.Add(objReader.ReadLine)
        End While

        objReader.Close()

    End Sub

    Private Sub btnSaveList_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSaveList.Click
        Dim saveFD As New SaveFileDialog()
        If saveFD.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
            Using objWriter As New StreamWriter(saveFD.FileName) 'Throws the exception here
                For Each line In lstList.Items
                    objWriter.WriteLine(line)
                Next
            End Using
        End If

    End Sub

    Private Sub lstList_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles lstList.SelectedIndexChanged
        lstList.Items.Remove(lstList.SelectedItem)
    End Sub
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You create two streams but only closing one at the end of reading the file. The [`OpenFile()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog.openfile(v=vs.110).aspx) method of the `OpenFileDialog` is creating a stream you doesn't close at the end so it stays open and locks the file. In your case you are using your own stream so you don't need the method `OpenFile()`.

**code for button #1 (read the file):**

```
openFD.Filter = "Text [*.txt*]|*.txt|CSV [*.csv]|*.csv|All Files [*.*]|*.*"
openFD.ShowDialog()
'openFD.OpenFile()

Using objReader As New StreamReader(openFD.FileName)
    While objReader.Peek <> -1
        lstList.Items.Add(objReader.ReadLine)
    End While
End Using
```

**code for button #2 (write the file):**

```
Dim saveFD As New SaveFileDialog()

If saveFD.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
    Using objWriter As New StreamWriter(saveFD.FileName) 
        For Each line In lstList.Items
            objWriter.WriteLine(line)
        Next
    End Using
End If
```

Comment: You don´t have to call `objReader.Dispose()` explicitly in the first `Using` block

Comment: Thank you @Sebastian, I simply removed `openFD.OpenFile()` and it worked.

Comment: You're welcome! You can optimize your code by using `Using`, so you have not to dispose / close the stream yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Opening a file for read will lock the file against writes and deletes; opening a file for write will lock against reads, writes and deletes.

You can override those locks but trying to both read and write a file at the same time creates its own set of problems.

There are two approaches to avoid this:

1. Read the whole file in and close before processing and writing. Of course the whole content has to be in memory.
2. Write to a temporary file, after closing the input and finishing writing delete the original file and rename the temporary file. This will not preserve attributes (eg. ownership, ACL) without extra steps.

However in your case I suspect you need to use a [`using` block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/using-statement) to ensure the file is closed after the read rather than depending on the GC to close it at some point in the future.

Comment: Thank you for this.